# Unable to access data in an ASP.NET MVC web application using Entity Framework and SQL Server database

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In an ASP.NET MVC web application, I have created the following entity:

```
[Table("tblEmployee")]
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

But, when I try to retrieve data from a database table called `tblEmployee` using Entity Framework, I get an error. What I have done until now is:

- Created a database `MVCDemo` with "." as server name and using Windows authentication containing a table called `tblEmployee`
- Installed Entity Framework
- Added `EmployeeContext.cs` class file to `Models` folder

Code:

```
namespace MVCDemo.Models
{
    public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

- Added a connection string to web.config file in the root directory

  ```
   <connectionSrtings>
       <add name="EmployeeContext" 
            connectionString="server=.; database=MVCDemo; integrated security=SSPI"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient;" />
   </connectionSrtings>
  ```
- Added Details actionResult to EmployeeController to show employee details:

  ```
    namespace MVCDemo.Controllers
    {
        public class EmployeeController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Employee
            public ActionResult Details(int id)
            {
                EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
                Employee employee = employeeContext.Employees.Single(e => e.EmployeeId == id);
                return View(employee);
            }
        }
    }
  ```

Finally, I added the following code to `Global.asax` to prevent initialization:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MVCDemo.Models.EmployeeContext>(null);
```

The problem is when I run the application I get this error:

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>
> The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

and when I comment connection strings out and try to reach

```
http://localhost:60613/Employee/Details/1
```

to show details of 1st employee, I get this error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: 'The underlying provider failed on Open.'SqlException: Cannot attach the file 'C:\Users\arya\source\repos\MVCDemo\MVCDemo\App_Data\MVCDemo.Models.EmployeeContext.mdf' as database 'MVCDemo.Models.EmployeeContext'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your tag name, it is incorrect. It will trigger the error definitely.

```
<connectionSrtings>
```

It should be:

```
<connectionStrings>
```

Update:
Since you have another issue, fix the last part of your connection string:

```
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Remove the semi-colon at the end of SqlClient.

Comment: It is a shame but true. I cant tell how disappointed I am and by the way, it is odd that I didn't get error for that misspell. But after getting that fixed, now I am facing this error: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient;' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: Dear David, thanks a lot. It worked. I accepted your answer, hope you do so.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I couldn't see your database connection. Yes you have teached the table but you didn't tell the program where to put those infos. Something like:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=databaseName")
```

Second possible reason is your program don't know where to go at the beginning. I had those error before and solved it with using default map.

Third reason, this probably not true but, you wrote "connectionSrtings" wrong. As I say, it's probably not that but I wanted to mention if it is.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Its a shame I misspelled connection string but after getting that fixed, this error is what I see: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient;' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details. any suggestions?

Comment: We can help you better if you share your database connection with us. You probably missed that. You must tell the system the database you want  to use. If you won't do that, system can't know the path.

Comment: Yes, sure. While creating database, I chose . for Server Name and Windows authentication for Authentication, created database and did as explained. Thank you again and let me know if I can provide any other information.

Answer (score 0):

This is because if you have the database named `MVCDemo` in the `SQL Server` then its fine, otherwise code first approach looking for `MVCDemo` database in SQL Server. If you dont have the database in SQL Server, then try this `connection string` to create the `mdf` file first.

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MVCDemo-20200820010246.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MVCDemo-20200820010246;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: Yes I want to have database on sqlServer but it seems that database is not connected to project to be read and I am getting this error now: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient;' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.